# Any software package suitable for expanding expression with multiple series to many orders?

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-software

I wish to expand expressions, such as the following, to at least 6 orders (possibly more).

$$Y=\frac
{(D - R\cos\theta + T.V.W)}
{D^3\left(
 X^{1.5}Q^3 
+3W.X^{1} Q^{2.5}
+3W^2X^{0.5}Q^2
+W^3Q^{1.5}
  \right)}
$$

With 
$$Q = \left(1-\frac{U^2}{V^2}\right), X = \left( 1  - 2\frac{r}{D}\cos\theta + \frac{R^2}{D^2} \right), W = \left(\frac{U\sin\theta}{V}\right)$$

and
$$  T = \left( 
\frac{D.W}{V.Q}
\right) 
\left( 
1+\sqrt{\frac{Q.X}{W^2}+1}
\right).
$$

Previously I have been using some old self-written code (VB6). But with the above expression I am running into overflow problems with term constants whose numerators and denominators exceed the maximum integer capability of VB6 on my 32-bit Win7 laptop (i.e +/- 7.92E28).

Is there any software package available for (and capable of) performing this kind of expansion?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is available for VB6 but the System.Numerics.BigInteger class allows integers of any magnitude to be stored in VB.

Comment: @Peter Foreman interesting, thanks, but it doesnt seem to be in VB6.